# ABCPdf change orientation of a specific page

Tags: c#, abcpdf

The code below creates a new PDF with landscape orientation. It uses ABCPdf component.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "da.pdf");

    var theDoc = new Doc();
    //theDoc.Read(filePath);

    // apply a rotation transform
    theDoc.MediaBox.String = "Legal";
    double w = theDoc.MediaBox.Width;
    double h = theDoc.MediaBox.Height;
    double l = theDoc.MediaBox.Left;
    double b = theDoc.MediaBox.Bottom;
    theDoc.Transform.Rotate(90, l, b);
    theDoc.Transform.Translate(w, 0);

    // rotate our rectangle
    theDoc.Rect.Width = h;
    theDoc.Rect.Height = w;

    // add some text
    theDoc.Rect.Inset(50, 50);
    theDoc.FontSize = 96;
    theDoc.AddText("Landscape Orientation");
    theDoc.AddPage();
    theDoc.PageNumber = theDoc.PageCount;
    theDoc.AddText("Page 2");

    // adjust the default rotation and save
    int theID = theDoc.GetInfoInt(theDoc.Root, "Pages");
    theDoc.SetInfo(theID, "/Rotate", "90");
    theDoc.Save(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "out.pdf"));
    theDoc.Clear();
}
```

Instead of creating new pdf, I would like to open an existing PDF and change the orientation of a specific page to landscape using ABCPdf. like 1st page will be in Portrait and 2nd will be on Landscape.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do so, or use "AddImageDoc" method, to insert a modified page...

BUT

Abcpdf doesn't allow to overwrite the source file. From "Save Method Documentation":

> ABCpdf operates an intelligent just-in-time object loading scheme
> which ensures that only those objects that are required are loaded
> into memory. This means that if you are modifying large documents then
> server load will be kept to a minimum. The original PDF document must
> be available for as long as the Doc object is being used.
>
> As a result **you cannot modify or overwrite a PDF file while it is read
> into a Doc object**. You will need to save your PDF to another location
> and then swap the two files around after the Doc object's use of the
> PDF is ended (with a call to Clear, Dispose, or Read with another PDF
> file).

So you will need always a "new pdf".

Comment: Thats fine. I wouldn't mind saving the file as a new pdf once the changes are done. I will try AddImageDoc and will get back shortly.